# Can I add custom colors to mercurial command templates?

Tags: formatting, mercurial

I want to use customized template for `hg log` which looks like this:

```
hg log --template '{node|short} {desc} [{date|age} by {author}]\'n --color=always
```

This in default terminal color is not very readable, so for instance I would like to make node red and desc green. How can I do this? In git I can define this kind of formatting like this:

```
git log --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset %Cgreen%s%Creset [%ar by %an]'
```

Is a similar thing possible in mercurial?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no way to do this directly in Mercurial, but if you're on a Unix-y system you could use [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_codes) to control the colors.  For example:

```
hg log --template "\x1B[31m{node|short} \x1B[32m{desc}\x1B[0m\n"
```

will give you the `node` in red and the `desc` in green.

On the Windows command prompt, you have to enable the [ColorExtension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ColorExtension) and the codes are the parameters to the color command (`help color` in the command prompt), so the equivalent would be:

```
hg log --template "\x1B[4m{node|short} \x1B[0;2m{desc}"
```

**Note:** in the second escape sequence, the `0` is to reset the text color and the `2` is to set it to green.  Without the `0`, it seems you get an inclusive-or of the color codes, which in this case would be yellow.

Comment: You can use the same mechanism on Windows with [Ansicon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon).

Answer (score 30):

As of 2013, Mercurial has direct support for [colors on templates](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/templates). You can also check that on *hg help templates*.

You must activate the color extension on your **.hgrc**:

```
[extensions]
color =
```

Then add some custom labels to be used later on on the template:

```
[color]
custom.rev = yellow
custom.author = bold
```

Then use the template referencing the labels (using **{label('labelname',field)}** instead of **{field}**:

```
hg log --template "{label('custom.rev',node|short)}  {desc}  [{date|age} by {label('custom.author',author)}]\n"
```

The example above highlights the node (revision) in yellow and the author of the commit in bold blue. As always, you can create an alias on your .hgrc:

```
[alias]
customlog = log --template "{label('custom.rev',node|short)}  {desc}  [{date|age} by {label('custom.author',author)}]\n"
```

**Update:** Tested version 2.5.4.
According to the [changelog](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew), this [works
since version 2.5](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/WhatsNew/Archive#Mercurial_2.5_.282013-02-01.29).

Comment: Is there a way to have different color for {diffstats}? i.e.: green for + red for -?

Comment: To see the built-in labels Mercurial itself uses, run the command with `--color=debug`; e.g. `hg log -l1 --color=debug`.